# Removing columns in synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am currently using dataflows in my current project, but unfortunately when I output the data to the sink node I get an error relating to one of the columns as it contains special characters.

Is there anyway of using the dataflow to remove the special characters in the column header? I noticed there is ways of cleaning the row data within the table, but it seems like I cannot get it to apply to the header itself.
Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you please provide sample input and output columns?

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216473/data-factory-special-character-in-column-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your source in the data flow, and add a Select activity to the source for the location column. Add Rule-based mapping, and select **column as** `name=='location#'`. Then, add the `regexReplace($$,'[^a-zA]','')` expression for **name as** as shown below:

[image]

Afterward, you will obtain the location column without special characters, as shown below:

[image]